# How to include framework dll's with my game so the user wont have to download them?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

In one of my previous threads someone said this was possible, so I did research. I couldn't find anything relevant, can anyone say how to do this, if it is possible?

Comment: Are you using the `XNA` framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the property of every referenced dll `Copy Local=true`

Comment: Thank you! Now users won't have to install the whole framework.

Comment: You're not supposed to do that. See my answer.

Comment: @AndrewRussell I guess in OP's particular case it's not a problem :)

Comment: Well he *should* consider it a problem, as he intends to distribute to end users ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14988709/165500) that the framework you are referring to is the XNA framework.

**You're *really* not supposed to be distribute Microsoft DLLs as loose files!** You're supposed to distribute the [**XNA redistributable**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914) only!

Using the DLLs without installing them properly can lead to various problems on end-user machines. And distributing them as loose files is against the EULA!

---

Speaking as a Microsoft MVP for XNA (yes, we still exist, for now):

The official word from Microsoft is that XNA is still "supported". Basically this means that **XNA is not suddenly going to break!!!**

The XNA framework installer will remain available from Microsoft's website. (Just like, for example, this [decade old](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=96) framework download). You'll still be able to reference it from your installer (eg: ClickOnce). But, if you don't want to require the download, you can distribute the installer yourself (hence: "redistributable").

It will still install successfully on all current versions of Windows. And should continue to install on future versions of Windows.

---

The recent [hullabaloo](http://ventspace.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/directxxna-phase-out-continues/) you may have heard about XNA is simply that Microsoft has made it public that XNA is no longer in development. All this means is that there will be no future versions. The existing versions **will still work!**

Comment: Thanks for your response, maybe you're right. I can include the redistributable version so there will be no errors(hopefully) and its not against the EULA. I learn something new everyday. Thanks again.